# Python GDAL package missing header file when installing via pip

Tags: python, gdal, ubuntu, installation

I asked [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336153/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip) before I realised this site existed. As this site it more appropriate, I'll ask it here too.

I'm trying to install gdal from pip `pip install gdal` inside a virtual environment (Ubuntu). It fails because it cannot find `cpl_port.h`

```
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2853:22: fatal error: cpl_port.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated
```

However GDAL is installed correctly and the header file is located at `/usr/include/gdal/cpl_port.h`. Is there some environment variable for GDAL that needs to be set in order for pip to find the header files?

Comment: I have similar issue on windows, installing gdal via pip in virtual env.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVLWP.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVLWP.jpg)

Answer (score 154):

selimnairb's answer is close but you wont have the headers unless you've installed libgdal-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
```

with that done,

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal

export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
```

and then

```
pip install GDAL
```

The compilation ran to completion and I have GDAL in my virtual env. Phew!

(edit 2018) Note:
To be sure that you install the correct version and avoid any problem.
retrieve the version with `gdal-config --version`.
and then:

```
pip install GDAL==version
```

Comment: Seems to be the only solution that worked.

Comment: Tried this on another system, and I think the combination of this plus @nickves answer is what actually does it.

Comment: Very good. In case, installed version of GDAL in system and python package differs, it fails. The solution is to find version of GDAL in system and instruct pip to install relevant python package version. In my case (Ubuntu 14.04) both are 10.0, so it helped `$ pip install GDAL==10.0`

Comment: I can confirm that this works on Ubuntu 16.04 with `pip install GDAL==1.10.0`.

Comment: On AWS Linux, it works for me but I had to update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with GDAL lib path and `$> sudo ldconfig`

Comment: This method works with pipenv too!

Comment: Also see this resource: https://mothergeo-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/how-to/gdal-ubuntu-pkg.html

Comment: It also works inside a docker container. thank you <3

Answer (score 39):

Τhe header files cannot be found for some reason. Maybe you you are operating inside a Virtual Enviroment or they are not where they should be for some reason. In any case you can specify the include dirs when installing gdal via pip.

first download python's gdal :

```
pip install --no-install GDAL
```

in later versions of pip (>= 9.0.0) `pip install --no-install` does not exist:

```
pip download GDAL
```

then specify where the headers are:

```
python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs=/usr/include/gdal/
```

then install it:

```
pip install --no-download GDAL
```

in later versions of pip (>= 9.0.0) `pip install --no-download` does not exist:

```
sudo python setup.py install --include-dirs=/usr/include/gdal
```

Here's another way to install gdal python:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python-gdal
```

after that open IDLE:

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

and you're good to go!

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer but I really need a way to install via pip as I will be creating isolated environments using virtualenv during CI process.

Comment: what is the output when you run 'gdal-config --version' and 'gdal-config --libs' ?

Comment: GDAL v1.9.1. `gdal-config --libs -> -L/usr/lib -lgdal`

Comment: @nickves I am trying to install GDAL using virtualenvwrapper in Ubuntu, and when I try your first line: `pip install --no-install GDAL`, I get the error: `__main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` Any idea?

Comment: Yes, It seems that gdal bindings are trying to find gdal-confing  within your virtualenv, and it fails because it's not there. A possible solution (I haven't test it!) is to create a symbolic link of your gdal-config to your virtualenv directory ( `ls -s /path/to/gdal/gdal-config /path-to-virtualenvs/your-env/bin/gdal-config` ).

Comment: I had the same problem as theJollySin using Ubuntu 13.04 - my complete answer is further down (too long for a comment ;)

Comment: I recently had a wonderful time installing GDAL on OSX. Currently, the latest Python bindings for GDAL depend on 2.1, but the latest available GDAL in homebrew is 1.11.3, and 1.11.4 for GDAL Complete. I installed via homebrew, `brew install gdal`, and used an older version of the GDAL Python package: `pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/usr/local/include/gdal/" 'gdal==1.9.1'`

Comment: @TestSubject I have recently installed python binding for GDAL 2.1 on OSX using the [compatibility framework](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks), and I have summarised the steps on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/256004/105890). Maybe you'll find this useful. The major issue is that the usage of the `gdal-config` binary is broken when using `pip`.

Answer (score 20):

After following a subset of this advice, this is how I got the Python GDAL 1.11.0 (the solution should be version-independent, see below) install to work on Ubuntu 14.04 with pip:

Install dependencies:

```py
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libgdal1h
```

pip install by passing along the include path (prefix with `sudo` for system-wide install) and instructing pip to install the version matching the system installed GDAL version:

```py
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal" GDAL==\`gdal-config --version\`
```

Comment: The higher rated answers from selimnairb and Paul Whipp didn't work for me on Ubuntu 15.10 and this one did.

Comment: The second line worked for me after apt-adding the unstable repositories from @nickves answer. Thanks to all!

Comment: Thank you, this ended up working for me.  Though I had to modify slightly as I'm attempting to stick to the cartodb installation as strictly as possible, I ended up using this as my final working install command:
`sudo pip install --no-use-wheel -r python_requirements.txt --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal"`

python_requirements.txt specifies an older version of gdal.  I doubt it would matter to be honest, but the entire pip install set completes successfully.  U 12.04x64

Answer (score 19):

## Installing Python package `gdal` into virtualenv on Linux

`GDAL` provides nice toolkit for GEO related operations. However,
installing it to virtualenv on Linux is not a trivial task.

This recipe describes, how to do that.

> **note**
>
> here I use lowercase `gdal` for Python package and upper case `GDAL` for
> general system wide library.

### Requirements

- allow using osgeo libraries (installed via `gdal` Python package) into
  virtualenv
- allow installing on Linux Ubuntu

### Installation methods

There are multiple methods for installation. One requires compilation
and takes few minutes more.

The other is using wheel package of `pygdal` package and is very quick.
Anyway, to create the wheel package one needs to create it once and the creation includes the compilation step anyway.

### About `GDAL` packages and versions

`GDAL` is a general C(++) based library for GEO related calculations.

`GDAL` utilities can be installed system-wide what makes shared libraries
available, but does not install Python package itself.

`GDAL` comes in different versions and each Linux distribution may by default install different version.

Python package `gdal` requires compilation and is not trivial to install
on Linux based systems as it expects few environmental variables to be
set. This makes installation into virtualenv more difficult.

Each `gdal` version might assume different version of `GDAL` and will fail
installing if expected version is not present in the system.

Python package `pygdal` is an alternative to `gdal`, which installs exactly the
same stuff as `gdal`, but does it in a much more virtualenv friendly manner.

`pygdal` comes in versions reflecting related `GDAL` version. So having `GDAL`
version 1.10.1 in the system you shall install `pygdal` version 1.10.1.

Python package `gdal` (as well as `pygdal`) uses root python package named
`osgeo` and has a set of submodules, one being `osgeo.gdal`.

If needed, other than default versions of `GDAL` can be installed and
used. This is out of scope of this description.

Wheel packages can be cross-compiled, this is also out of scope.

## Installing `GDAL` into system

As `pygdal` requires `GDAL` shared libraries to be present, we must install them first.

Assuming `GDAL` is not yet installed, calling `gdal-config` will complain
and give you a hint how to follow up:

```
$ gdal-config --version
The program 'gdal-config' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
```

Follow the hint and install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
```

Each distribution may use different version of `GDAL`. To find out which
we use:

```
$ gdal-config --version
1.10.1
```

Now you know, `GDAL` is installed and the version is 1.10.1 (the version
can vary).

## Install `pygdal` from source package (requires compilation)

Currently, `pygdal` is provided only in tar.gz package, which contains
package sources and requires compilation.

Assuming, the version of `GDAL` is `1.10.1` and that our virtualenv is
already activated:

```
$ pip install pygdal==1.10.1
```

It may take a while to complete, is it needs numpy, which may also
require some compilation. Just wait.

Check, it is installed:

```
$ pip freeze|grep pygdal
pygdal==1.10.1.0
```

From now on, you may use osgeo package in your Python code as you like
in exactly the same manner as if you would install it by `gdal` Python
package.

## Creating wheel package for `pygdal`

Note, that wheel packages must be created for exactly the same
architecture, namely, must match:

- CPU architecture
- OS (Linux/Windows)

In our case, it must also match the version of `GDAL` installed.

Following steps can be done in virtualenv or not, as you like.

First, make sure, wheel package is installed:

```
$ pip install wheel
```

Assuming, you have `GDAL` installed and it has version 1.10.1:

```
$ pip wheel pygdal==1.10.1.0
```

and wait, until it completes.

After this, you shall find subdirectory wheelhouse and it shall contain
packages with extension `whl`:

```
$ ls wheelhouse
numpy-1.9.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
pygdal-1.10.1.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

## Install `pygdal` from wheel packages

Installation from wheel formatted packages is much faster (a second
compared to minutes), as it does not require compilation.

Note, that directory with wheel packages can have any name, we will use
just the name wheelhouse.

Activate virtualenv first.

Ensure, you have in wheelhouse directory both required wheel packages
(for `pygdal` and `numpy`).

Ensure, `GDAL` is installed and the version matches version of `pygdal`.

Install `pygdal` from wheel package:

```
$ pip install pygdal==1.10.1.0 -f wheelhouse
```

The -f wheelhouse shall point to the directory with whl files.

There is no need to install `numpy`, it gets installed automatically.

Comment: this anwser builds on other great answers here, tries to give complete instructions for the details, where I got stuck and adds steps for using wheel package format for speeding up repeated installs into virtualenv.

Comment: `pygdal` for the win!! [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pygdal/): "Virtualenv and setuptools friendly version of standard GDAL python bindings" <3

Answer (score 9):

Yes, doing the following before running PIP appears to work:

```bash
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal

export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem with the pip installing gdal is that it only gets the bindings, not the entire library, so it can get tricky. One way to solve it is to use the pip command to download - but not install. Then you tweak the header location from the config file. Then you pip install that. meh.

I was having the same problem but realized that writing a [fabric script to recompile gdal and generate the python bindings](https://gist.github.com/2955440) was going to take less time. You even get the benefit of filegdb with that. Go ahead and use tha gist I wrote or tweak it to your hearts content.

Answer (score 4):

After looking right and left for a solution, here is something that works for me on Ubuntu 14.04, even from within a virtualenv with no access to the system packages :

- Install dependencies :

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libgdal1h libgdal1-dev
  ```
- Set the compiler flags :

  ```bash
  export CFLAGS=$(gdal-config --cflags)
  ```
- Install the version corresponding to the system libraries (at the time of writing Ubuntu Trusty is using the 1.10 headers) :

  ```bash
  pip install GDAL==1.10.0
  ```

Comment: also worked for me on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4):

On Fedora 24 which has GDAL 2.0.2 in its repositories, I had to install the Python package like this:

```bash
pip install \
  --global-option=build_ext \
  --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal/" \
  GDAL==2.0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

While a while later, this provides the include path without having to bail out of pip installation: One can set the include path using an environment variable.

Assuming the headers are in /usr/include/gdal, issue an

`export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal`

before running pip.

Comment: Using this, I get "extensions/gdalconst_wrap.c:2732:18: fatal error: gdal.h: No such file or directory" even though gdal.h is present in `/usr/include/gdal`

Comment: Does using C_INCLUDE_PATH instead/additionally helps=?

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use virtualenv and setuptools friendly version of standard GDAL python bindings [pygdal](https://github.com/dezhin/pygdal).

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar problems on a Mac. This is how I resolved it:

Firstly, I set up a virtual Python 2.7 environment using virtualenv. The Python distribution was installed in a directory called 'env'.

I then used fink to install gdal

```bash
fink selfupdate
fink update-all
fink install gdal
```

I also installed gdal-dev but this may not have been required since it might have already been installed with gdal.

I checked the version installed using:

```bash
gdal-config --version
```

On my installation, it produced the result
1.11.1

The fink installation of gdal installed the cpl_port.h header file in /sw/include/gdal1. Check your own installation. I then entered:

```bash
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/sw/include/gdal1
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/sw/include/gdal1
env/bin/pip install pygdal==1.11.1
```

That seemed to work for me but I haven't tested installation yet.

Answer (score 2):

## Installing via Pip with Single Command

Assuming the GDAL develop package is installed and the header file versions are correct, the only command needed to install GDAL from PyPI repos is as follows:

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal" gdal
```

This obviously assumes the location of the header files is `/usr/include/gdal`.

## Install Up-to-date GDAL

In order to install GDAL with the pip command above, the version of the header files need to be similar to the version that pip will do the build. GDAL has an updated binary reference at: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries.

### How to Install on OpenSUSE

Following the link above, there is a URL embedded further down point to an up-to-date set of GIS packages for **OpenSUSE 42.1** http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:/Geo/openSUSE_Leap_42.1/Application:Geo.repo

```
zypper ar -f <URL>
```

Replace  with the appropriate package. And if not using `zypper` there is more info at https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar error while trying to install the python GDAL bindings on a mac (OS 10.10.5). I installed the base GDAL software from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks using the "Complete" download. I had to set three environment variables.

```bash
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Headers
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Headers
export LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/Current/unix/lib
```

The final piece was to add `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs` to my `PATH`.

```bash
echo 'export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

After that pip was able to install GDAL for python. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the virtualenv specific aspect of the question:

```
pip3 search gdal
```

> ```
> GDAL                      - GDAL: Geospatial Data Abstraction Library
> pygdal                    - Virtualenv and setuptools friendly version of
>                             standard GDAL python bindings
> ```

Beware that `pygdal` may require a different version of GDAL, compared to what the `GDAL` package of python bindings requires.

---

Below is what I used to get it on recent versions of Fedora (20 and 23).

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/gdal pip install gdal
```

Answer (score 1):

**These gdal Packages 0.10.1 work well for Ubuntu 12.04 :**
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable/+sourcepub/4353415/+listing-archive-extra

**gdal Packages 0.10.1 for other ubuntu version :**
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable/+packages?field.name_filter=gdal&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=

Comment: I had trouble with `gdal 1.10.1` too, and just did the following `pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal" gdal==1.10.0`

Answer (score 1):

I've had same problem on Windows 10.
After some experiments I came with this solution.

1. Download and install Python 3.6 (if not installed)
   after installation alter environment variables
   `PYTHONPATH=c:\python36`
   `PATH=C:\python36\Scripts\;C:\python36\;%PATH%`
2. Download *.whl for correct python version from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal
3. Download and install http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
4. `pip install *.whl` (*.whl from step2)

Comment: thnx, i thought python have installed automatically environments, but then i removed and recreated environments as you suggested everything works like a charm.

Comment: Your link for visual studio doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Docker we open sourced our container, that simplifies using GDAL and Python 3.  The container captures the steps outlined above to allow you to quickly use GDAL with your apps.

[thinkwhere/gdal-python](https://hub.docker.com/r/thinkwhere/gdal-python/)

Answer (score 1):

This approach worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
pip3 install gdal==$(gdal-config --version)
```

Or as a part of a Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
                libgdal-dev \
                python3-pip
ARG CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
ARG C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
RUN pip3 install gdal==$(gdal-config --version)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) and need a recent version of GDAL for Python, here is an example of what part of a `.travis.yml` file would look like:

```yaml
language: python

env:
  global:
    - CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
    - C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal

before_install:
  - sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
  - sudo apt-get -qq update
  - sudo apt-get -qq install libgdal-dev gdal-bin

install:
  - pip install gdal==`gdal-config --version`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a Debian-based distro, the GDAL python libraries are available via your package manager and can be simply installed with

`sudo apt install python-gdal` or `sudo apt install python3-gdal`

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 with conda in docker container (jupyter stack)

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libgdal1-dev -y
gdal-config --version
export CFLAGS=$(gdal-config --cflags)
pip install GDAL==1.11.2
```

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu, a simpler solution to install the latest gdal for python3: install library files via `libgdal-dev`, and python wrapper via `python-gdal`

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-gdal
```

for python2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gdal
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also encounter problem whith memory usage.

When running `pip install gdal==2.2.3` gcc is launch to compile something and it raises memory usage.

If you don't have enough memory, the compiler fails, with a message like

> 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4

To fix it, you need to add more ram or free some.

Answer (score 0):

This was how I installed gdal 2.x (NOT 3.x) on Ubuntu 18.04 (I assume 16.04 would be the same) inside a virtualenv for python3:

```
# add the apt repo 
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y

# install gdal==2.2.3 on system
# NOTE: these may change in the future, you can check versions with: 
# apt-cache policy <package name>
sudo apt install -y libgdal20=2.2.3+dfsg-2 libgdal-dev=2.2.3+dfsg-2
sudo apt install -y gdal-bin=2.2.3+dfsg-2 python3-gdal=2.2.3+dfsg-2

# ensure that it worked
gdalinfo --version  # should print 'GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20'
# start a python3 interpreter NOT inside your virtualenv
>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>> gdal.__version__  # should print '2.2.3'

# activate virtualenv 
source .venv/bin/activate

# install inside virtualenv
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
pip3 install gdal==2.2.3

# ensure that it worked
# start a python3 interpreter INSIDE your virtualenv
>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>> gdal.__version__  # should print '2.2.3'
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55717357/1526703) worked for me.

Summary: instead of `pip`, just use `brew`:

```
brew install gdal
```

Answer (score 0):

My context

*Linux Mint 19, 32 bit,
python 3.6*

I did this:

```
pip install GDAL
```

I get these errors (just part of it):

```
i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
Command errored out with exit status 1 ...
```

And this works for me.
I followed the instructions in this [page](https://mothergeo-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/how-to/gdal-ubuntu-pkg.html) (read carefully):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin 
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev 
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal 
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal

sudo apt install g++
```

Then:

```
pip install GDAL==<ogrinfo version >
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new python environment and install gdal first using the following command:

`mamba create -n new-env gdal -c conda-forge` or `conda create -n new-env gdal -c conda-forge`

Check gdal installation: `gdalinfo --version`
If you get an output like this `GDAL 3.5.3, released 2022/10/21`

You are all set!