# No ogr module despite having gdal installed?

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

I am trying to use the mapping component of the wonderful [PySAL](http://pythonhosted.org/PySAL/) package, but for some reason I do not have the ogr module.  I was under the impression that it came packaged with [gdal](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/).  Am I missing something?

```
import gdal
import ogr

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-ef9eb3418665> in <module>()
----> 1 import gdal
      2 import ogr

ImportError: No module named gdal
```

**UPDATE:**  I am afraid I was in a bit of a hurry to catch a plane, so I failed to include some critical information.  I already installed python-gdal using the apt-get method described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip), because I wanted to leave little to chance.  Is it possible that the package manager did not install it correctly?

```
choct155@choct155-Q550LF:~$ sudo apt-get install python-gdal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-gdal is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  firefox-globalmenu libfftw3-3 libgeos-3.3.3 libogdi3.2 libxerces-c28
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
```

I am afraid I am not finding osgeo either...

```
from osgeo import gdal

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-a04b80bf4e65> in <module>()
----> 1 from osgeo import gdal

ImportError: No module named osgeo
```

Additionally, I should add that I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: I have the same problem and I installed gdal (it says it's in /usr/bin/python2.7/dist-packages. If I run a script that has 'from osgeo import gdal', I get the following error message: 'ImportError: No module named osgeo'. Did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just ended up upgrading all of [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) when the next iteration was released.  I should also note that GDAL was accessible in R, so I am guessing it had something to do with the particular constellation of Python dependencies.  Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 12):

Use these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gdal
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
```

Comment: This answer basically duplicates information linked to or in the question and does nothing to explain why the module wasn't present despite having installed gdal.

Comment: this answer actually worked for me

Comment: not working for me

Comment: did not work for me in Ubuntu 16.04 either

Comment: @raphael, same here. My example of gdal's osgeo package not being found after installing gdal. https://github.com/TileStache/TileStache/issues/299#issuecomment-345737905

Comment: for python3 use ``sudo apt install python3-gdal``

Answer (score 1):

Normally the import should look like this:

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
```

But if you see "ImportError: No module named osgeo", then you didn't install the GDAL Python package correctly. (Hint: if you are using Windows, I strongly recommend [this](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)).