# Running python GDAL in repl.it

Tags: python, gdal

The code sharing repl.it has a python interpreter, and proudly hails that any library is available for import.

https://repl.it/site/blog/python-import

This does include the GDAL library. However, the typical GDAL installation experience, to the best of my knowledge, involves
1. installing drivers, `libgdal-dev`
2. setting environment variables
3. AND THEN installing GDAL.

Sequences like this have been discussed in this related question:
[Python GDAL package missing header file when installing via pip](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip?newreg=5dd99fd8f561468c952da6fd23d2aea5)

Given these extra shell requirements, is it impossible to install GDAL from a python interpreter alone, as seems to be required for the available repl.it interface? Or is there a way to make this happen from within python?

https://repl.it/@ValerieAnne563/RunningWithGDAL

Comment: It has been [raised as a bug](https://repl.it/bugs/p/cant-import-pypi-module).  `rasterio` (requires GDAL) also fails.