# GDAL 2.3.1 is installed but the llinux terminal is using GDAL 2.2.2

Tags: python, gdal, numpy, linux

I asked this question before realising this site existed:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476826/gdal-2-3-1-is-installed-but-the-llinux-terminal-is-using-gdal-2-2-2

I've installed GDAL 2.3.1 using pip on a ubuntu 16.04 in a python environment. The package is in the correct site-packages directory and yet when I run a python script, I receive this error:

Error 1: NUMPY driver was compiled against GDAL 2.3, but the current library 
 version is 2.2

The error then ends in a `segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

When using `gdal-config --version`, the output shows `2.2.2`.

I want to know how to change the version of gdal that linux appears to be using from 2.2.2 to 2.3.1 but I have no idea how to do this.

UPDATE

As asked, here's the method I used to install gdal and the outputs. I followed the method in 
[Python GDAL package missing header file when installing via pip](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip)

I installed it in a python environment built to be able to run tensorflow 1.8.0 with Cuda 9.2 using a GPU - I don't know if that makes any difference

COMMAND

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
```

OUTPUT

`Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Suggested packages:
  libgdal-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgdal-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/6,496 kB of archives.
After this operation, 40.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libgdal-dev.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 233309 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgdal-dev_2.2.2+dfsg-1~xenial1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgdal-dev (2.2.2+dfsg-1~xenial1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up libgdal-dev (2.2.2+dfsg-1~xenial1) ...`

COMMAND

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal

pip install gdal
```

OUTPUT

`Collecting gdal
Installing collected packages: gdal
Successfully installed gdal-2.3.1`

Could it be something to do with libgdal-dev installing 2.2.2?

Comment: Yes, you're compiling the python bindings against the gdal 2.2.2 source. Either download the gdal 2.3 source (I haven't bothered doing this for years) or just install a pre-compiled version from the conda-forge channel using a [conda env](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) - `conda create -n gdal23 -c conda-forge "gdal>=2.3"` then `source activate gdal23`

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing that but now I have this error:                             
    `ImportError: /home/conor/miniconda3/envs/gdal23/lib/python3.6/site- 
     packages/osgeo/../../../libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol:  
     sqlite3_column_table_name`                                                                                                                Is this caused by a previous installation of gdal? I tried removing duplicates of libgdal.so.20 but this has been ineffective

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu, a simpler solution to install the latest gdal for python3: install library files via `libgdal-dev`, and python wrapper via `python-gdal`

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-gdal
```

for python2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gdal
```